# Does it make a difference how I get the user to load a script into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php

I know this is very small and maybe not even worth taking the time to consider or change, but I'm still interested (also maybe this is significant for bigger files). I am injecting one of several JS scripts into my webpage, based on a HTTP get parameter: the server (PHP) looks at the parameter's value and loads the corresponding script. My question is, is there, hypothetically, any difference between doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo getScriptLocation($_GET["foo"]); ?>"></script>
```

and this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo getScript($_GET["foo"]);
</script>
```

?

That is, is there any perceived difference for the client based on whether I send them the script, or the script's location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the script location, the client makes an http requests to get it in the background and will execute it when it's ready. This let your page load to continue and reduces the size of the page requested.

The requested script can also be cached by the client, which makes this additional request instantaneous.

I usually prefers to pass the location. For one script it works fine. If you have tons of them, you should group the scripts in a way to reduce the number of requests, especially on mobile clients where lot of simultaneous requests are very bad.

Answer (score 2):

They won't notice a difference, however if you use the src attribute the file can be cached on the users machine, giving you better performance.